# woman posting a picture of herself on social media

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, pictures, social-media

From a halachic perspective, is it modest for a religious woman - especially someone who is single - to post her picture profile on social media?

Comment: Not sure why my comment was deleted, but this question could be improved with reasons why you think it may or many not be a problem.

Comment: read the history of edits on this.

Comment: @mevaqesh your now-deleted comment directly addressed content of the post that's no longer in it. So I deleted the comment.

Comment: Possibly, a form of "Lifnei Iver" (stumbling block before the blind) if someone is intentionally disguising the way she looks. (BTW, interestingly, enough, I think the pic problem is more prevelant with men than with women.)  I think the larger problem may, of course, be in any subsequent descriptive profile, though. Then again, there are a number of newspapers & publications that don't place any pics of women, anywhere.

Comment: what's she doing on social media?

Comment: this would seem to be a question of das moshe vs das yehudis; or the letter of the law vs the correct way to live.